# Silverlight 4: how to make CustomList items draggable

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop

I have a list of object that need to be displayed and moveable on the canvas. Could you please describe idea how to do that?

Thank you in advance for you help and time.

P.S. Actually I have some kind of solution (it is listed here: [Silverlight 4: why items are not moveable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553188/silvelight-4-why-items-are-not-moveable)) but it doesn't work.

I very appreciate any thoughts or ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround myself and it is provided in the linked topic. If somebody know the better solution or have any other thoughts, please let me know.

Thanks!